# Proper way of accessing the `history` object from redux thunks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom, history

I have some redux thunks that need to call `history.push()`.

It first I was trying to avoid having to pass the `history` object in the thunk call, so I did the following change in my code:

From this:

**index.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

To this:

**index.tsx**

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from "./history";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App/>
  </Router>
);
```

**history.ts**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

But now that I've come to the SSR phase of my project, this has become a nightmare. Because I cannot call `createBrowserHistory()` on my server code (NodeJS).

**QUESTION**

The pattern above is very comfortable to use both with redux thunks and some other helper functions that need to call `history.push()`. I simpy have to `import { history } from "@src/history";` from whatever file that needs it and use it directly.

But since this is conflicting with my SSR code, I'd like to know what is the best practice / recommended approach to this situation. Should I get the `history` object from the components by using `const history = useHistory()` and pass it to the thunks / functions that need it? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: You may be able to integrate a history object into your redux store via [conencted-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), otherwise I think the common practice is to add the history object to the action. See also [Deep Redux Integration](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/deep-redux-integration).

Comment: @DrewReese I'm using `@reduxjs/toolkit`. I think they have a [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware) for extra arguments that is similar to this. But that would still require me to call `createBrowserHistory()`, which I might replace to an empty object `{}` on server, I guess.  I think I'll go with passing the `history` as a payload approach. It will be less complicated for my use case.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant to mention that I didn't think the redux integration route would work for SSR, so you're left with passing the `history` object along with any asynchronous actions.

Comment: @DrewReese will do that. Thanks. Do you happen to know which type should I use for the `history` object that I'll pass? I'm also having issues with that type and asking this question on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664937/how-to-type-the-history-object-from-usehistory-that-will-be-passed-to-a-func

Comment: I'm actually fairly unfamiliar with Typescript, but provided a link in a comment in that SO question that may help.